# How can I make a JS webpage which automatically opens a MetaMask payment prompt?

Tags: web3js, metamask

How can I make a JS webpage which automatically opens a MetaMask payment prompt?

Hello,

I am coding some web3 enabled webpages.

I want to make a webpage which does the following in JavaScript:

```
a) Loads the web3 resource
b) Automatically opens a prefilled payment request prompt in MetaMask of say 0.001 ETH to address XYZ. This should happen as soon as the webpage is loaded.
```

Anyone knows how to do this as simply as possible?

Vesa

Comment: I guess if you send a transaction of 0.001 eth to your contract as soon as the page is loaded metamask will open the prompt to confirm it.

Comment: thank for the clear response, it helps me a lot. I have another point I am struggling to understand as I'm new in programming. I have a contract deployed on ropsten, and I want to interact with it and call the function isOpen() but I get this error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'isOpen' of undefined at index.js:492 Here is the code I use: window.addEventListener('load', async function () { if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') { console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name) window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider); var toAddress = '0x3cC56eD2f4

Comment: Please open a second question thread.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this into an HTML page, and loading it from a server should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@0.19.0/dist/web3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('Web3 Detected! ' + web3.currentProvider.constructor.name)
                window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

                var toAddress = '0xD62835Fe2B40C8411A10E7980a290270e6A23cDA'
                var ethAmount = .1

                web3.eth.sendTransaction({
                    from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
                    to: toAddress,
                    value: web3.toWei(ethAmount, 'ether')
                }, function (error, result) {
                    if (error) {
                        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Something went wrong!"
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Track the payment: <a href='https://etherscan.io/tx/" + result + "'>https://etherscan.io/tx/" + result + "'"
                    }
                });
            } else {
                document.getElementById('output').innerHtml = 'Please download and install Metamask: <a href="https://metamask.io/">https://metamask.io/</a>'
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. I want a script that can be loaded from any client browser without need for any server. Possible?

Comment: When I say "loading it from a server", I am talking about the restriction that Metamask has about running on local web pages: [Http(s) - Web Server Required](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#globe_with_meridians-https---web-server-required)